# I am developing a video website in which admin will upload 1 GB size of videos, what server I can use so that it can be play properly on front end

Tags: php, laravel-5, video, server, streaming

I am developing a video website in which admin will upload 1 GB size of videos, Which server I can use so that it can be play properly on front end.
I have look for
Wowza
Amazon S3
Digital Ocean

Comment: It will highly depend on how much resources you feed into it and how optimised your application is, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question :)

Comment: Your server has nearly no influence on your front end performance! Hint: i's a horrible idea send such a giant file just for video. Try to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Practical warning: be aware of AWS charging data transferred out of their regions (e.g. to Digital Ocean droplets).
Take a look about this DigitalOcean Alpha Object Storage here: https://www.digitalocean.com/products/storage/object-storage/